# AngularJS loop inside array

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to loop inside an array returned as the result set of an API GET call, but can't seem to find a way on how to do so. Can someone help me with an example on how to loop on this array to display it on the app view? Thanks

Below is the result set format returned:

```
Object {Result: Array[5]}
Result: Array[5]
0: Object
  id: 1
  name: "Mark"
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Note: 
- I've already tried using ng-repeat but couldn't display data in my view. To display data in my view I have to do it this way

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="client in my clients">      
        <tr>
          <td>
           1
          </td>
          <td>
            {{client.0.name}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

As you can see I've statically written 0 here to get the first record, while I need to loop from 0 to maximum the length as provided. So is there anyway I can do this with ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Brocco/nU8p2/1/) based upon this model:

```
$scope.Object = {
    Result: [        
    {id: 1, name: "Mark 1"},        
    {id: 2, name: "Mark 2"},        
    {id: 3, name: "Mark 3"},        
    {id: 4, name: "Mark 4"},
]};
```

And am looping through it like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="client in Object.Result">
            <td>{{client.id}}</td>
            <td>{{client.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem :) I was missing .Result

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand agreed, which is why I attempted to create the item  he copied from his console as a JSON object in the controller I created. Your answer is quite valid too, only difference is that I have the full result in my scope field and you are using the child field (Result). I upvoted your answer as it certainly works too.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` is the standard utility for looping through arrays and displaying them in views, if you want more advanced features you should check out `ng-grid` or other data grids:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results">
   <h2>{{result.id}}</h2>
   <h4>{{result.name}}</h4>
</div>
```

Before all that, you need to get results (the result of API call) onto your controllers `$scope`:

```
app.controller("someController",function($scope,someService){
  someService.getData().success(function(data){
    $scope.results=data.Result;
  })
});
```

EDIT:

[Here's a working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pwHhXFULSWX37n3Sc2RB?p=info), feel free to modify it to show us why exactly ng-repeat is not working for you.

Comment: ng-repeat will never return anything from this result set

Comment: @AD.Net please read the question updates. The answer provided by Mohammad didn't add any value to the problem

Comment: @MChan, I don't see any updates in your question, see my plunk. Rather than down voting and being vague as to why `ng-repeat` isnt working for you, feel free to provide us with a plunk.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand I am not sure if your last reply will be considered professional by SO but I find it offensive and have already reported it. Thanks.